# Proving $ax+b$ is a linear function

Tags: linear-algebra

$L\colon\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$ be given by $L(x)=ax+b$ over the scalar field $R$.

I understand for that a function to be linear, it must adhere to the properties of additivity and scalar multiplication. From, what I have gathered $L$ violates the property of scalar multiplication
                    $a(L(x)) \neq L(ax)$ for $x \in R$.
I just started learning linear algebra, but I think I might have done something wrong since $L(x)=ax+b$ seems like it would be linear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function is what's called AFFINE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), it's not linear.

Comment: Well, it is not linear in the sense of linear transformation in linear algebra, but it is linear, and that's how it is usually called in high school, because geometrically it is a straight line.

Comment: It's a linear polynomial regardless of whether or not it is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

You are right .
$$L(x)$$
is not linear try not to confuse it because its graph is a line. IF one of the linearity properties do not apply then it is not.IN general
$$F(x)=ax+b$$
is linear iff b=0

Answer (score 1):

There are ultimately a lot of different ways we use the term "linear". In the context of linear transformations, $L(x) = ax+b$ is linear if and only if $b=0$. Perhaps you could explore a proof for that instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, but I often see people using "linear" to mean "polynomial of degree 1" outside of linear algebra contexts, especially in introductory e.g. calculus courses. In fact, I say this to my calc tutoring students *all the time* and I didn't realize it's actually wrong until now.

Comment: It's not wrong to call it a linear polynomial. The function is not a linear transformation as a map of vector spaces, but that doesn't mean it's not a linear polynomial function. This whole question arises from confusion of different uses of the word linear.